# WPF C#. Привязка к свойству вложенного объекта

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно организовать привязку к свойству вложенного объекта.
Прикладываю свой пример:

```
class Child
{
    public Property_of_Child { get; set; }
    public set (string someString)
    {
        Property_of_Child = someString;
    }
}

class Parent
{
    public Property_of_Parent { get; set; }
    public Child child_1 = new Child();

    public Parent ()
    {
        Property_of_Parent = "Some String Of Parent";
        child_1.set("Some String Of Child");
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Parent parent_1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    parent_1 = new Parent();
    someStackPanel.DataContext = parent_1;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="someStackPanel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=child_1.Property_of_Child}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: К какому свойству вы хотите привязаться, к `Property_of_Child `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что у вас используются `поля`, а не `свойства`. Привязаться можно только ко `свойствам`. Поэтому:

1)  Делаем из поля `parent_1` свойство.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Делаем из поля parent_1 свойство.
    public Parent Parent_1 { get; set;};

    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         Parent_1 = new Parent();
         someStackPanel.DataContext = Parent_1;
    }
}
```

2) Делаем из поля `сhild_1` свойство.

```
class Parent
{
   public string Property_of_Parent { get; set; }

   // Делаем из поля сhild_1 свойство.
   public Сhild Сhild_1 { get; set; }

   public Parent ()
   {
        Сhild_1 = new Сhild_1();
        Сhild_1.set("Some String Of Child");
   }
}

class Child
{
    public string Property_of_Child { get; set; }

    public set (string someString)
    {
        Property_of_Child = someString;
    }
}
```

3) Сама привязка. Обращаемся к родителю, от родителя обращаемся к дочернему и у дочернего объекта привязываемся к его свойству.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="someStackPanel">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Parent_1.Сhild_1.Property_of_Child}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Вместо слова `биндинг`, я понимаю в некоторых кругах его все еще используют, лучше использовать простое русское слово `привязка`, т.к. слово `binding` правильно произносить как `байдинг`, запомните "бантик", я завязываю на бантик, `байдинг`, иначе среди зарубежных коллег вы рискуете выглядеть как Равшан с Джамшутом в этом [ролике](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gP9zujM5TWk).

Comment: Да вы правы, но я не лингвист-полиглот и на точность произношения не претендую. Некоторые слова могу произнести не правильно в силу привычки.

Comment: Я все понимаю. Наша сфера деятельности предполагает возможность работы за рубежом. А вот такие профессиональные слова-паразиты могут вырваться в самый неподходящий момент. В лицо, конечно, в силу толерантности вам ничего не скажут, может только переспросят, что вы хотели сказать. А вот за пивом после работы... Как говорится, лучше уж не давать лишнего повода.